# Meaning of different taglib-standard*.jar

Tags: java, apache, jsp, jstl

When I land on the download page of [Apache Taglibs](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi), I can see 4 types of JARs, namely:

1. impl
2. spec
3. jstlel
4. compat

What is the difference between each of these variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Anu Shibin Joseph Raj, as said over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39972724/5813861)  , each used for its own different purpose.

> spec            <-- contains Apache's implementation of the API classes 
>   impl            <-- contains the implementation of tags from the 1.1
>                           namespace http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/* 
>       jstlel          <-- contains the implementation of tags from the 1.0
>                           namespace http://java.sun.com/jstl/* and uses the original JSTL 1.0 version of EL 
>       build-tools     <-- build support such as checkstyle rules 
>       compat          <-- contains the implementation of tags from the 1.0
>                           namespace but uses the JSP container's implementation
>                           of EL (which will be 2.1 or later).